# SQL Query to select all products from WooCommerce with SQL Query

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, export-to-csv

How can I select all the products from WooCommerce (WordPress-Plugin) with all products data, product variations, product type and product prices so that it can export data and use it on some other website?.

I'm using MySQL Workbench to run this SQL Query.

Comment: can't you use wordpress itself to export?

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/product-import-export-for-woo/ reduce your effort. Use this free plugin

Comment: it's and old version of woocommerce(2.6) so it;s not working.

Comment: @azmat I can not use wordpress itself to export. It's not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It worked this time with `woocommerce` > `Tools` > `Export and Import`.